# How do I zip and download a file from s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm on a machine that is connected to my S3 bucket. I'd like to download a file.

I tried to use `sync`.

```
aws s3 sync s3://my_bucket/my_file/file.csv
```

It told me I didn't have enough arguments. Is there another way I could do this?

Comment: You need to define source and destination location in aws s3 command , add a "." at the last of the command which will tell the aws s3 to save the file to the present directory or you can specify the exact folder location.  "aws s3 sync s3://my_bucket/my_file/file.csv . "

Answer (score 1):

Try `aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket/my_file/file.csv .`

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Examples at the bottom of the page.

Comment: What step can I add if I want to turn a directory into a zip?

Comment: I get a "permission denied" message. Do I want to use chmod to open up permissions?